# Python/Pandas : Do a value_counts() for each value of a column

Tags: python, pandas

sorry to bother you but I'm struggling with my code.

What I've been trying to do is to determine the repartition of a column for each value of another column of my dataframe.
I'm going to show an example with the iris dataset, it might be more clear.

I use this code :

```
import sklearn.datasets

data, target = sklearn.datasets.load_iris(return_X_y=True, as_frame=True)

data["target"] = target

data
```

With this dataset, I have 5 columns :  ['sepal length (cm)', 'sepal width (cm)', 'petal length (cm)',
'petal width (cm)', 'target']

My goal is, for example for each unique values of the column sepal length (cm), to have the repartition of the column target with value_counts(). So like, for the rows where sepal length (cm) = 2, I want to do data["target"].value_counts, and the same for the rows where sepal length (cm) = 1, 3 etc... until I've done it for all the different values of sepal length (cm) and I have the repartition of the target for each value of this column.

I obviously have an idea but it's not very practical.

```
df1 = data.loc[data['sepal length (cm)'] == 2]

display(df1['target'].value_counts(normalize=True)*100)
```

It worked, but if I have to do that for each value of sepal length (cm), it's really a long process.

So if someone know how to do that automatically, it might save my day !!
Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to group the dataframe by `sepal length (cm)` and find the number of occurrences in each group by the `target` column. If this is the case, you can try something like this:

```
data.groupby(['sepal length (cm)'])['target'].agg('count').reset_index()
```

This gives you an output like this:

[image]

Again, I'm not sure if this is the thing you need.